# Eclipse 4.2 Validation errors with JSP scriplets and CDATA

Tags: eclipse, jsp, validation

I'm trying to upgrade my projects from RAD 8.5 (Eclipse 3.7 I believe) to RAD 9.1 (Eclipse 4.2) and so far everything seems to be going smoothly.  Except for JSP files.

Whereas they seem to be validating properly in Eclipse 3.7, they are generating a lot of errors in Eclipse 4.2.  Specifically, when vars are defined in CDATA sections, they are marked as undefined elsewhere in the scriptlet.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _wireOC = 
    <%  int x=10;
        x = x *50;
    %>
    <%= x %>;
//]]>
</script>

<p>This is a test <%=x %></p>

<%
    x=x+1;
 %>
```

Eclipse will mark any reference to x as "- x cannot be resolved to a variable" outside the `CDATA` block.  Any references to `x` within the `CDATA` block are okay.

I've tried to trick the validator by using the JS `//` comments but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is this a problem with Eclipse 4.2 JSP validator, or is there some config of the validator that can be done for this?

Comment: Is your doctype XHTML?

Comment: @developerwjk There is nothing defined in the jsp file itself, so I tried using the default setting of the project Web Content Settings to be HTML and XHTML but neither made any difference.